# Match multiple time-series columns?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I’m a new noob to the forum, would appreciate if anybody could provide some help.

I’m using Excel 2013. I have 5 sets of columns; each includes a Time column and a Price column. However, the 5 individual Time columns of the 5 sets don’t match, i.e., the dates are not continuous (there are different time breaks in each set) and they begin from different starting dates.

I want to do two things, the second being optional (as I believe Excel is incapable of delivering).

(1) Insert a new column set with common dates (the common dates/entries from Time1 to Time5) on the left and prices 1-5 on the right. E.g. (note the dates are NOT continuous):

```
Common Date   Price 1   Price 2   Price 3   Price 4   Price 5
20010304      938       33        988       5532      5732
20010308      25        23325     2358      664       8798
20010309      677       3         234       32423     234
20010311      9835      32434     3529      352       392
20010314      498       4534      43398     945       495483
```

(2) This is very different from (1); make the dates column continuous. That is, include the non-common dates as well by displaying the blank/breaking dates. E.g. (note the dates are continuous, no breaks, not even weekends):

```
Date       Price 1   Price 2   Price 3   Price 4   Price 5
20010304
20010305
20010306   677       3
20010307
20010308                       234
20010309             9845                          234
20010310                                 32423
20010311   43435    
20010312             234                           324
20010313
20010314   898
```

FYI, I’ve tried `IF(COUNTIF())` formulas; they simply sort out common entries within the same row. I messed around `VLOOKUP` and was too stupid to figure things out, the same goes for `INDEX/MATCH`. Perhaps the solutions lie within PivotTable or VBA, of which I have zero knowledge.

[image: Example]

Comment: I don’t understand the question.  Please show the input data that are supposed to produce your example result for question (1).  And maybe make the two examples consistent.  And why do you say that you have Time columns but then give examples showing only dates?  Can there be two or more rows in the same column that have the same date?

Comment: And when you provide the input data that I asked for, above, I suggest that you delete that image at the end.  You’ve done a good enough job of explaining, generally, what your data look like; this screen-full of data that don’t match the examples is just a distraction.

Comment: @Scott, the image was invisible and was made visible by another person's edit, not the OP. Anyway, if that's the data structure, my suggestion is below.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have a data layout of alternating time and price, where time is really a number that represents yyyymmdd.

Option 2 is actually quite easy. Identify the smallest "time" value and put it into a cell. In the cell below it, increment that time value by one day. Then select both cells and drag the fill handle down. Excel will keep auto-incrementing the values and you end up with a list of consecutive dates. (you could also use a formula along the lines of =A1+1 and drag that down)

The next five columns will hold the price values and they will be looked up with a formula. Here is a screenshot of the scenario:

[image]

The consecutive time values start in cell A13. Cell B13 has the formula:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A13,dataset1,2,0),"")
```

"dataset1" is a range name I assigned to the cells A1 to B6, but you could use the direct cell references $A$1:$B$6 instead. I've also created range names for the other data sets, i.e. "dataset2", "dataset3", etc. The formula in cell C13 is

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A13,dataset2,2,0),"")
```

With the range names, I only need to adjust the number of the data set and then copy the formula down.